# Indexing into nested arrays VS using a reference to the deepest level?

Tags: php, arrays, optimization, nested, reference

Given a deeply nested array: `$array = array('nested' => array('so' => array('deep' => array())));`

...which is faster/'better'?

```
$array['nested']['so']['deep'][0] = 'a';
$array['nested']['so']['deep'][1] = 'b';
$array['nested']['so']['deep'][2] = 'c';
```

or

```
$deep = &$array['nested']['so']['deep'];
$deep[0] = 'a';
$deep[1] = 'b';
$deep[2] = 'c';
```

Or are they the same? If so, is one preferable, and why?

Comment: You need to profile that (see [xdebug etc.](http://www.sitepoint.com/faster-php-apps-profile-your-code-with-xdebug/)).

Answer (score 3):

**Keeping a reference is faster and easier to manage**, typically.  However, it may not make a difference unless you are accessing it multiple times.  Hashing is fast.  In tests I ran recently I found that hashing is even faster than I had previously supposed.  The more levels you bypass by reference, the more improvement you'll see, though.

**However, the most important thing for me is that it is easier to maintain**.  The performance increase is likely to be negligible in most cases.  I wouldn't bother doing it for performance, but if it makes your code more readable, then I'm all for it.

Answer (score 2):

You probably missed another variant:

```
$deep[0] = 'a';
$deep[1] = 'b';
$deep[2] = 'c';
$array['nested']['so']['deep'] = $deep;
```

Faster and better depends a lot, these terms are quite broad. Faster to type? Decide on your own. Faster to execute? I don't think it makes worth to know in such a general form, this can make a difference in concrete places, but then you need to metric it in concrete as well to find out.